# Nested ng-repeat filter

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-filters

I have this table with ng-repeats that needs to be filtered

```
<tbody ng-repeat="item in model | limitTo: limits track by $index | filter: { UserId: filter.User, Type: filter.Type}">
  <tr class="timesheet-day-block">
    <td colspan="6">
      <span class="timesheet-date">{{item.TaskDate | dateFilter}}</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="timesheet-table-rows" ng-repeat="list in item.TimesheetList" ng-form="logged">
    <td>{{list.ProjectName}}</td>
    <td>{{list.UserName}}</td>
    <td>{{list.Date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
    <td>{{list.Task}}</td>
    <td>{{list.TimeWorked}}</td>
    <td>
      <span style="width: 85%">{{list.Note}}</span>
      <button class="active-delete-button" ng-click="removeTask(list)" style="display: inline-block; float:right">✖</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

If I put my filter to the second ng-repeat it's filtering but `timesheet-day-block` remains visible but without data after it.  I need hide that block when there is no TimesheetList data, and tried to fix this by moving my filter to first ng-repeat, but it's not working.

My data looks like this:

```
{
    "TaskDate": "2015-01-04T00:00:00",
    "TimesheetList": [
        {
            "WorkItemId":24,
            "ProjectId":3,
            "ProjectName":"Hello world",
            "UserId":12,
            "UserName":"Juliya Pogrebnaya",
            "Date":"2015-01-04T22:00:00",
            "Task":"#34 : drfth",
            "TimeWorked":56754.0,
            "Note":null,
            "InProgress":false
        }
    ]
}
```

I have set up a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vKwwM11icL4lrGrCJYyK?p=info).

Comment: one problem is that `track by` must be after all filters. You are going to need a custom filter that can do the lookup in the nested array. Can't do what you want with a simple property filter

Comment: Are you sure you want to include 2 `<tr>` for each iteration of the outside repeat?

Comment: @ryanyuyu, I don't understand what about you saying

Comment: You've got two separate table rows in each iteration of the repeat.  Is this intentional?  Hiding one won't hide the other automatically, unless the entire repeat is suppress.

Comment: @ryanyuyu the idea is that the first repeat won't print anything if the filters don't have any matching data. OP's problem is to get filter working on top level

Comment: @HUSTLIN please provide what the objects look like.  It's really not clear at what point you have no data.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Objects is Data.json [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/vKwwM11icL4lrGrCJYyK?p=info)

Comment: @ryanyuyu just updated plunker